# Replacing numbers of which you only know certain digits

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

If I have a list of numbers like this:

```
list = {0.3565127, 0.8656421, 0.231479879, 0.39698787, 0.536987651},
```

which are all between 0 and 1, each having lots of digits, and whose precision is not known (and also not important). I don't know their exact values. (It could be a list of hundreds of numbers, so we don't know each of them exactly).

Yet I know some of them have the form `0.?969?????????`, where the `?s` represent digits I do not know; besides; the digits known are all within the first five digits behind the decimal point.

So, how can I construct a pattern object (like `x_^2` for symbols) for replacing numbers that match the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Jason B:

```
Select[list,
  MatchQ[
    TakeDrop[
      If[Negative[#2], ArrayPad[#1, {Abs[#2], 0}], #1], 
      Clip[#2, {0, \[Infinity]}]
    ] & @@ RealDigits[#] &, 
    {{}, {_, 9, 6, 9, __}}
  ] &
]
```

> ```
> {0.396988}
> ```

Where the first list in patterns specifies the pattern for digits on the left side of the decimal point and the second for those on the right.

For earlier versions `TakeDrop` can be replaced with `Through[{Take, Drop}[##]] &`

---

Old answer

Not exactly pattern matching, but working:

```
Select[
 list,
 Mod[Floor[# 10^4], 10^3] == 565 &
]
```

> ```
> {0.356513}
> ```

Same approach, slightly modified:

```
Pick[
   list,
   Mod[Floor[list 10^4], 10^3],
   565
]
```

---

Probably slower string approach:

```
StringCases[
  ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ list,
  StartOfString ~~ _ ~~ "." ~~ Repeated[_, {2}] ~~ "65" ~~ __ ~~ EndOfString
] // Flatten // Map[ToExpression]
```

> ```
> {0.356513}
> ```

or, matching your question the best:

```
Cases[
    ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ list,
    _?(StringMatchQ[#, RegularExpression[".\\...698.*"]] &)
] // Flatten // Map[ToExpression]
```

> ```
> {0.396988, 0.536988}
> ```

Comment: @garej no because there the `_` is repeated exactly twice.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you! Yes it is an equally good alternative. Oh, but is there a  convenient method in Mathematica to form a pattern object in such cases? What I have in mind is things like wild cards within the numbers, like this: `0.*565****...`, where the * is a wild card.

Comment: @User18 take a look at the last on I've just edited.

Comment: @Kuba, I see, by the way, how to avoid `ToExpression` to round up the string number?

Comment: @garej rounding is done by the interface, if you take a look at FullForm or cell expression, you will see all is there. You can change number of displayed digits somewhere in preferences. Moreover, ToString respects that so I had to use `InputForm`.

Comment: @Kuba, may be I'm missing something but 787 or 878?

Comment: @garej could you elaborate?

Comment: @Kuba Ah, I didn't refresh my web page just now. Thank you. The new code looks less simple than the first method, but I see now what is required to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: @User18 Yes, but is more flexible, e.g. you can use `".\\...6.8.*"` regex while with first method you would have to check specific digits

Comment: The question states that we do not know how many `?`. Does it concern only `?` after the pattern? If so, it is better to reformulate the question in this respect.

Comment: @garej The question states "I don't know how many digits these numbers have." not how many are behind `?`.

Comment: @Kuba, but your string example with `698` found pattern after `??`. Why not more or less? Select and Pick return nothing with `698`...

Comment: The numbers are all between 0 and 1, each having many, many digits, but the precision I do not know, and it is I think irrelevant. I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: @garej Select and Pick are aiming in `?,?565?...` while the last one is looking for `?,??698?...`. Where by `?...` I mean repeated `?` and by `,` I mean decimal point.

Comment: @Kuba - this is trickier than it should be :-)   If you try the `Select` above on the list `{0.969, 0.0969, 0.00969, 0.3565127, 0.8656421, 0.231479879, 
0.39698787, 0.536987651}` it only catches one

Comment: Thank you @Kuba, your answers are really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that OP wants a pattern object for use in replacement rules, so this does the trick,

```
{0.969, 0.0969, 0.00969, 0.3565127, 0.8656421, 0.231479879, 
  0.39698787, 0.536987651} /. 
 a_ /; MatchQ[
    First[RealDigits[a, 10, Automatic, -1]], {_, 9, 6, 9, __}] -> 4
(* {0.969, 4, 0.00969, 0.356513, 0.865642, 0.23148, 4, 0.536988} *)
```

**edit** Thanks as always to @J.M. for helping me write better Mathematica code.

Comment: @Kuba, see the edit

Comment: Thanks ;) p.s. `Drop` will be safer, and `PatternSequence` seems to be redundant. `MatchQ[ Drop @@ RealDigits[1.096956], {_, 9, 6, 9, __} ]`

Comment: @Kuba, `Drop` doesn't seem to do the trick all the time either, see `Drop @@ RealDigits[0.063548]`

Comment: @JasonB Right, please see my edit. p.s. I always felt like `RealDigits` output doesn't fit *list manipulation* practices in MMA.

Comment: That's probably not a real life example but still: `MatchQ[RotateLeft @@ (RealDigits[22.1111111111111111]), {_, 1 .., 
  2, __}]`

Comment: @Jason Thank you! It is enjoyable to learn from your answer.

Comment: @User18, my pleasure - this is a question that really should have an easier answer I would think.

Comment: No `Quiet[]` necessary: `{0.969, 0.0969, 0.00969, 0.3565127, 0.8656421, 0.231479879, 0.39698787, 0.536987651} /. a_ /; MatchQ[First[RealDigits[a, 10, Automatic, -1]], {_Integer, 9, 6, 9, __Integer}] -> 4`.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. for the comment!